# Custom Error Message do not work for http://www.myserver.com/index.htm

Tags: lotus-domino

I'm creating a custom General Error Message (in domcfg that will replace the standard HTTP404) 
The custom Error Message is displayed for URL like http://www.myserver.com/foo.nsf (where foo.nsf does not exists on the server).

QUESTION: Why is not displayed the custom Error Message for URL that do not contain ".nsf"?
How can this Custom Error Message be displayed for http://www.myserver.com/index.htm instead of the standard HTTP 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the HTTPMultiErrorPage notes.ini parameter. With this you can point to an HTML error page for non nsf errors (404). See the following for more information:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/07282008024243PMKMKPXA.htm

You can add a substitution rule for the path you add to the HTTPMultiErrorPage notes.ini parameter in order to control the error page in a database instead. The following blog post has details on that:
http://dpastov.blogspot.dk/2012/01/error-pages-in-domino.html

Comment: feedback: I added the rule for all http 404 and redirect them to /foo.nsf (since for this I already display the message) BAD BAD idea it make a infite loop since foo.nsf send a HTTP 404 ! so let's put the real URL of my custom General Error Message as defined in the domcfg.nsf.

Comment: feedback2: problem now ALL HTTP404 are sending back a redirection to myserver.com/myDB.nsf/myCustomGeneralErrorMessage?openForm<br>This is a problem since I need to know what was the URL (I read parameter especially the language) it *redirect* so I loose the inital URL.<br>I try to add a 2nd rule with "Incoming URL pattern: /*.nsf"
that will not override anything, in hope that this "more specific" rule will have a higher priority. It don't help.